# Lacking one element in the solution to linear equations by LAPACK

Tags: c++, blas, armadillo

I am really confused about the solution I get from a system of linear equations. My goal is to solve linear equation: `A*x = e` by a function in lapack. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "/usr/include/armadillo"
#include "/usr/local/include/lapacke.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    arma::fvec alpha( n );//define a vetor alpha with a size 3
    arma::fvec beta( n );//define a vector beta with a size 2
    alpha << 1 << 2 << 3 << arma::endr;//assign 1,2,3 to alpha;
    beta << 0.3 << 0.6 << arma::endr;//assign 0.3, 0.6 to beta;
    float a = 0.1;
    arma::fvec e = arma::zeros<arma::fvec>( n );//define a vector e with all element equal to 0;
    e( n - 1 ) = beta( n - 2 ) * beta( n - 2 ); //the last element of e equals to the square of the last element of vector beta;
    arma::fvec tri_alpha = alpha - a;
    LAPACKE_sgtsv(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, n, 1, &( beta[ 0 ] ), &( tri_alpha[ 0 ] ), &( beta[ 0 ] ), &( e[ 0 ] ), n );
    cout << e.t() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the vector alpha is on the diagonal and vector beta is on the sub-diagonal and super-diagonal to construct the tridiagonal matrix, assume it to be T. The following is the explain of the function `sgtsv`.

```
LAPACKE_sgtsv( int matrix_order, int n, int nrhs, float *dl, float *d, float *du, float *b, int ldb)
```

and

```
B is REAL array, dimension (LDB,NRHS)，On exit, if INFO = 0, the N by NRHS solution matrix X
```

In my case, B = e, I output e finally and it is `(0, -0.0444,   0.1333)`, obviously, the right answer should be `(0.0148,  -0.0444,   0.1333)`, then the first element is wrong or may be lacking, could anyone do me a favour? thanks. By the way, the library I am using is armadillo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/d29/sgtsv_8f.html) of `sgtsv()`, the upper (`DU`) and lower (`DL`) diagonals of the tridiagonal matrix `A` will be overwritten as the linear equation is solved.

> On exit, DL is overwritten by the (n-2) elements of the second super-diagonal of the upper triangular matrix U from the LU factorization of A, in DL(1), ..., DL(n-2)."

And :

> On exit, DU is overwritten by the (n-1) elements of the first super-diagonal of U.

The issue arises because `beta` is supposed to be the upper diagonal `DU` and the lower diagonal `DL` at the same time.

The solution is to duplicate `beta` :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "/usr/include/armadillo"
#include "/usr/local/include/lapacke.h"

//#include "/usr/local/include/armadillo"
//#include "lapacke.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    arma::fvec alpha( n );//define a vetor alpha with a size 3
    arma::fvec beta( n );//define a vector beta with a size 2
    alpha << 1 << 2 << 3 << arma::endr;//assign 1,2,3 to alpha;
    beta << 0.3 << 0.6 << arma::endr;//assign 0.3, 0.6 to beta;
    float a = 0.1;
    arma::fvec e = arma::zeros<arma::fvec>( n );//define a vector e with all element equal to 0;
    e( n - 1 ) = beta( n - 2 ) * beta( n - 2 ); //the last element of e equals to the square of the last element of vector beta;
    arma::fvec tri_alpha = alpha - a;

    arma::fvec betabis( n );//define a vector betabis with a size 2...copy of beta
    betabis=beta;
    LAPACKE_sgtsv(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, n, 1, &( beta[ 0 ] ), &( tri_alpha[ 0 ] ), &( betabis[ 0 ] ), &( e[ 0 ] ), n );
    cout << e.t() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```